# 20.04 black screen on boot, when system has been shut down for a while

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 20.04, startup

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04 LTS (5.4.0.-42-generic) on my ThinkPad E495, Ryzen 5 3500U with Vega Graphics. I sometimes experience a black screen on boot. However, the weird thing is, this always happens when my machine has been shut down for a while (a few hours, for example). If I shut down and then immediately start up, I don't have this problem and everything works fine.

When encountering this problem, a forced restart always solves the problem on the next run.

Comment: Completely black screen, or does it go through POST and then show a black screen?

Comment: It does go through POST and then the black screen sppears. Please let me know if you need additional info

Comment: The next step is to check out your logs. I'd recommend installing `ksystemlog` and then checking the logs after it happens again. So, when it happens again, reboot until it gets into the full OS and then check the logs as your first action when logging in.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that

Comment: @KGIII what should i be looking for in the system log?

Comment: The problem happens now in every 2 of 3 boots. First try: black screen after POST. --> I force reboot --> Second try: Grub selection screen appears after POST. --> I choose Ubuntu --> again black screen. --> I force reboot --> Third try: Like second try, but after choosing Ubuntu, the system boots successfully. This sequence has happened multiple times

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs? There should be some standing out. Without knowing what the errors are, we can't really move forward.

Comment: @KGIII The only errors I see are:
29.08.20 20:10 systemd Failed to start VirtualBox Web Service.
29.08.20 20:10 bluetoothd Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
But it doesn't really seem like they are related to my problem.

Comment: Wait... Are you running Ubuntu in a virtual machine with VirtualBox?

Comment: @KGIII No, I use VB only to run Windows 10 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the boot-repair tool solved my problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```